# How can i open crontab file to add new task?

Tags: cron

firstly i copied crontab file into new file (samah-crontab) using these commands:

```
crontab -l > samah-crontab
crontab samah-crontab
sudo service cron restart
```

I tried to do this:

```
file = open("/home/pi/samah-crontab","a")
file.write("50 22 * * * sudo python /home/pi/ON.py")
file.close()
```

I want to open crontab to add new task without using this command:

```
crontab -e
```

Also i tried to open this file "I noticed it while doing crontab -e" in each time i do "crontab -e" there new id for the file appears !! As(wP4Rji)

```
    file = open("/tmp/crontab.wP4Rji/crontab","a")
    file.write("50 22 * * * sudo python /home/pi/ON.py")
    file.close()
```

But nothing well!!!
i can't add new task without using "crontab -e". Why?

My idea is to add new task using python file and not as used to do this using edit command on terminal.

Any comment ?

Thanks

Comment: crontab is an installed binary (linux is modular).  You have to pass the `-e` flag to crontab in order to open it for editing.  In order to do this you need to interact with crontab programmatically, not just open the crontab file.  Check this out https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-crontab/

Comment: well, i understood... but why i have this error "ImportError: No module named crontab" ? i'm already installed it from the link

Comment: How did you install it?  Are you using virtualenv or anaconda or any other sort of virtual environment manager?

Comment: I tried to install it using this command:[sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule]. Then from the link u get abov                                                                                                                                                                                      by clicking on "Download python-crontab-2.0.1.tar.gz".                                                                                                              Finally, i tried to do this but didn't work:1-Download and install ActivePython 2-Open Command Prompt 3-Type pypm install python-crontab

Comment: Do you have pip installed?  You could try `pip install python-crontab` if you do.  The error you received is telling you that it cannot find the python-crontab module in its packages.  Try opening the Python REPL and entering `help('modules')` and see if python-crontab is installed as a package.